# Save data from MS Access form to another table in the same MS Access database?

Tags: database, ms-access

I need help for how to save data from MS Access form to another table in the same MS Access database !

I have 2 tables

```
Table1 -> I called it Data and this table have all the data that generate the form with unique ID
Table2 -> I called it SavedApplications and this table have multiple rows, what i needs that each row to get the data from the form of the first table after the user press the save button
```

In more simple words. Table 2, first row have unique ID = 1 with some other data in the same row but different columns ! :D and that data came from form that generated from table1

i hope i described my Q very well!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the comment you made on kefash' answer, it sounds to me like you are trying to populate a field in the 1st table with the data in the second?

This is done in the design view of your first table, by giving the applicable field in the lookup tab under field properties a display control of either combo or list box, depending on your needs. Afterwards, change the row source type to a table/query and in the row source, you select the table with your dropdown data.

Did that answer the question or did I completely misunderstand?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by creating a new form from the table that called SavedApplications then i replaced the generated text boxes with new combo boxes & i choosed to get the data from the table that called Data then i mentioned the selected item saved in the the text box field that removed in SavedApplications

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between both tables. Is it that you want to have the same data saved in two different tables? If so I would suggest you revisit you database design.

Comment: No the data is not saved in 2 differenet tables but the the first table have the data for combo boxes and the 2nd table i need to set the choices that have been selected by the user.

and there is no relation between those tables it is 2 different tables one for data that has been already entered and other one for saving the selected data with new ID

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question. your second statement made it much clearer. If you want to avoid doing too much coding the simplest way would be to use an append query to get the user's selection into the second table.